# Spring Batch with Multi-Tenant

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-tenant

OK, I'm sure someone else has run into this and has solved it, but it appears it is beyond my understanding of Spring.
I have a Spring Boot (2.2.4) application that I'm using Spring Batch to read a bunch of records from a text file and import them into a MySQL database. This was working just fine, but now I have a requirement to make the application multi-tenant. I was able to get Spring Boot app to be multi-tenant by passing a Header in (X-TenantID), but now the Spring Batch no longer works. Why?
Here is teh error I'm getting. `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0`
Full Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
DataAccessUtils.java:97
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:784) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
JdbcTemplate.java:784
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:809) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
JdbcTemplate.java:809
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:308) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:308
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:166) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
SimpleJobRepository.java:166
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Method.java:498
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
AopUtils.java:344
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
TransactionAspectSupport.java:366
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
TransactionInterceptor.java:99
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Method.java:498
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
AopUtils.java:344
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy215.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:440) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
AbstractJob.java:440
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:314) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
SimpleJobLauncher.java:147
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Thread.java:748
```

edit:
I'm setting the tenant id using a HandlerInterceptorAdapter...

```
public class TenantInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  private String defaultHeader = "X-TENANT-ID";
  private String defaultTenantId = "default";

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    log.debug("TenantInterceptor::preHandle");
    log.debug("Default Header: " + defaultHeader);
    log.debug("Default Tenant ID: " + defaultTenantId);
    try {
      String tenantId = defaultTenantId;
      if (defaultHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("Authorization")) {
        log.debug("Using the 'Authorization' header so we need to get the value from the JWT");
        String authToken = request.getHeader(defaultHeader);
        try {
          tenantId = JwtUtil.getClaim(JwtUtil.getTokenFromBearer(authToken).get(), "tenantId");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      } else if (defaultHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("X-TENANT-ID")) {
        log.debug("Using the 'X-TENANT-ID' header so just get the value from it.");
        tenantId = request.getHeader(defaultHeader);
        log.debug("TenantID: " + tenantId);
        if (tenantId == null || tenantId.isEmpty()) {
          tenantId = defaultTenantId;
        }
      }
      // TODO: Security checks
      // We need to ensure that the user making the request has the permissions
      // to make a request for the this tenant (Client/Customer)!
      TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenantId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
      ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    TenantContext.clear();
  }
}
```

TenantContext

```
public class TenantContext {

  private static ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static String getCurrentTenant() {
    return currentTenant.get();
  }

  public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
    log.debug("Setting tenant to " + tenant);
    currentTenant.set(tenant);
  }

  public static void clear() {
    currentTenant.set(null);
  }

}
```

And my BatchConfig

```
public class BatchConfig {
  @Autowired
  JobRepository jobRepository;

  @Autowired
  EntityManagerFactory emf;

  @Autowired
  WheelItemDao wheelItemDao;

  @Autowired
  DuplicateJurorDao dupJurorDao;

  @Autowired
  JurorDao jurorDao;

  @Autowired
  EventDao eventDao;

  // @Autowired
  // DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public Job wheelImportJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps,
      ItemProcessor<WheelItem, Juror> jurorProcessor, ItemProcessor<WheelItem, WheelItem> wheelProcessor,
      JobExecutionListener listener) {

    // @formatter:off
    Step wheelImport = steps.get("wheelImport")
      .<WheelItem, WheelItem>chunk(100)
      .reader(reader(null))
      .processor(wheelProcessor)
      .writer(wheelWriter())
      .build();

    Step jurorImport = steps.get("jurorImport")
      .<WheelItem, Juror>chunk(1)
      .reader(wheelItemReader())
      .processor(jurorProcessor)
      .writer(writer())
      .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
      .throttleLimit(125)
      .build();

    return jobs.get("wheelImportJob")
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
      .listener(listener)
      .start(wheelImport)
      .next(jurorImport)
      .build();
    // @formatter:on
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaItemWriter<Juror> writer() {
    JpaItemWriter<Juror> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return writer;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaItemWriter<WheelItem> wheelWriter() {
    JpaItemWriter<WheelItem> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return writer;
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<WheelItem> wheelItemReader() {
    JpaPagingItemReader<WheelItem> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    reader.setQueryString("select w from WheelItem w");
    reader.setPageSize(5);
    try {
      reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return reader;
  }

  @Bean
  public JobExecutionListener listener() {

    return new JobExecutionListener() {

      @Override
      public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // @formatter:off
        eventDao.save(
          Event.builder()
            .active(true)
            .eventType(EventType.RECONTITUTE_WHEEL_STARTED.id)
            .note(EventType.RECONTITUTE_WHEEL_STARTED.label)
            .createdDt(LocalDateTime.now())
            .updatedDt(LocalDateTime.now())
            .build());
        // @formatter:on
        wheelItemDao.truncateTable();
        dupJurorDao.truncateTable();
        // De-activate all current Jurors.
        jurorDao.updateActive(false);
        JurorProcessor.counter = 0;
      }

      @Override
      public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // @formatter:off
        eventDao.save(
          Event.builder()
            .active(true)
            .eventType(EventType.RECONTITUTE_WHEEL_FINISHED.getId())
            .note(EventType.RECONTITUTE_WHEEL_FINISHED.getLabel())
            .createdDt(LocalDateTime.now())
            .updatedDt(LocalDateTime.now())
            .build());
        // @formatter:on
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public ChunkExecutionListener chunkListener() {
    return new ChunkExecutionListener();
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public synchronized FlatFileItemReader<WheelItem> reader(
      @Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}") String pathToFile) {
    FlatFileItemReader<WheelItem> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToFile));
    flatFileItemReader.setName("Wheel-Reader");
    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    return flatFileItemReader;
  }

  @Bean
  public LineMapper<WheelItem> lineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<WheelItem> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setStrict(false);
    // @formatter:off
    tokenizer.setNames(
        ...
     );
    tokenizer.setColumns(
        ...
    );

    // @formatter:on
    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<WheelItem> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(WheelItem.class);

    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    return defaultLineMapper;
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(150);
    taskExecutor.initialize();

    return taskExecutor;
  }

  @Bean(name = "myJobLauncher")
  public JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
  }
}
```

The Batch Job is being launched via a HTTP call into my RestController.

```
JobExecution jobExec = jobLauncher.run(
          job, 
          new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .addString("fullPathFileName", UPLOADED_FOLDER + UPLOADED_FILE).toJobParameters());
```

Comment: You either provide some more code for us so we can see what you have done or you want to check some other example projects (like [this one](https://bytefish.de/blog/spring_boot_multitenancy/)) to find the difference.

Comment: (i assume) wherever you pass this "tenant header" - spring batch is not aware of/doesnt provide it...(please provide your db&batch configuration as the "routing" of the tenant)

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is for serving http requests. Your `jobLauncher` works on its own thread pool. You don't seem to transport the `tenantId` to the thread where the db query is executed.

Comment: Here is how I'm launching a Job from the Service class. ```JobExecution jobExec = jobLauncher.run(
          job, 
          new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .addString("fullPathFileName", UPLOADED_FOLDER + UPLOADED_FILE).toJobParameters());```

Comment: Where do you pass the `tenantId` to the job (I still don't see it), who is actually calling `getCurrentTenant()`?

Comment: @second I think that might be my problem... How do I pass the tenantId to the Job and how do I tell the Job to use the tenantId? So far all of the TentantID stuff is being handled through the magic of Spring Boot AutoConfiguration and Annotations.

Comment: What technology do you actually use for the communication with the db (`hibernate`?). What "multitenant model" are you aiming for (different db's, different schema' s, all-in-one)?

Comment: I'm using the default Hibernate JPA that comes packaged with Spring Boot. The multi-tenant model is different schema's same DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208151/discussion-between-jacob-miles-and-second).